# What's the purpose of a drill symbol?

Tags: orcad, drill

I use OrCAD environment for designing PCBs but I've never thought about what is the purpose of a Drill Symbol in padstack creator.  The diameter is set in the **Drill** bookmark and other parameters like antipads or thermal pads in Design Layers. I can see it in the layout file. What is that used for?

[image: Drill symbol]

Comment: You don't include mounting pads in your board designs? I'm not sure what the question is, why are there drills? Even via's require drills...

Comment: it's part of the "package" sent to a board manufacturer. They may use it; they may have another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're used to create a drill chart, which some PCB manufacturers use to double-check things like the match-up of the CNC drill files and the Gerbers.

I seldom-to-never send it with the Gerbers and drill file. In my experience, not much goes wrong on that account and I doubt they bother looking at it. From [this](https://www.eurocircuits.com/pcb-design-guidelines-mechanical-layer/) site:

[image]

Comment: Hi Spehro. Your post has explained everything. Thank you.